# iTunes Store says my card is invalid

Tags: ipad, itunes-store

My iPad is telling me that my card is invalid and I've used it before. When I go to the payment method my security number is gone from the info. When I input the number it says my payment method isn't valid. I don't know what I need to do. My card works and I've used it before. Why can't I use it now?

Comment: Sounds like your card is being declined or in some other way is invalid. I would call your card issuer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your subscriptions or recent purchases for an outstanding charge made to your account.

Check your subscriptions on your iPhone/iPad/iPod touch- https://support.apple.com/en-ph/HT202039

Check all of your recent downloads by visiting:
http://reportaproblem.apple.com and signing in.

If both subscriptions and recent purchases arent showing a charge then you should contact AppleCare via 1-800-MY-APPLE and ask to speak to iTunes. You should expect a 15-25 minute wait since iTunes is always busy. If you can call in the morning between 8am-11am, not too many people call Apple that early.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately this doesn't seem like a problem that we can solve.  If you're sure you're entering the card details correctly, and that the card is still active and you can use it elsewhere you need to call your card issuer and possibly [get in touch with Apple](https://www.apple.com/support/itunes/contact/).

Comment: Why was my answer downvoted? The support offered here is community based and there are some things (like checking details of a iTunes gift card) that we can't do.